# Apache not Sending POST Parameters to Index URL

Tags: apache, post

I am having a problem sending POST parameters with my relatively fresh Apache install.

In my document root, I have a file test.html which has the following:

```
<form action="/test" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="param" value="test" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

My .htaccess file sets the index file to be serve.php, as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex serve.php
```

Inside serve.php, I simply print out the POST parameter as follows:

```
<?= $_POST['param'] ?>
```

As written, this does not work.  If I change the method to GET (and also change the serve.php file to access GET) it works.  If I explicitly specify the action to be "/test/serve.php" it works.

Somehow it appears the POST parameters are being lost in translation to the index file.  Thoughts on why?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your POST data get lost when redirecting from `/test` to `/test/`.

Try `<form action="/test/" method="POST">`

Comment: Wow .. I just had the same exact problem and this comment helped me narrow it down to a trailing slash rewrite rule .. glad I only banged my head for half an hour instead of the couple hours this bug might have deserved.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering that the GET is working due to the parameters being contained within the URL, whereas, in POST they do not?

**POST**
Submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form) to the identified resource. The data is included in the body of the request. This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of existing resources or both.

Just wondering if the variables contained within the body of the request aren't being passed through by the Apache directive, perhaps its something Apache didn't think would be required?